# error While Creating custom timer job

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, timer-jobs

I am creating the custom timer job, but getting error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.
below is my code....can any one help on this...this code is for removing items from list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace WebAnalyticsTimerjob
{
    public class WebAnalyticsReport : SPJobDefinition
    {
        public const string JobName = "WebAnalyticsReport";
        public WebAnalyticsReport()
            : base()
        {

        }

        public WebAnalyticsReport(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType lockType)
            : base(jobName, service, server, lockType)
        {
            this.Title = "WebAnalyticsReport";
        }
        public WebAnalyticsReport(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp)
            : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {
            this.Title = "WebAnalyticsReport";
        }
        public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {

            //SPSite mySite = this.Parent as SPSite;
            SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
            SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["Tasks"];
            SPListItemCollection listItems = taskList.Lists.TryGetList("Web Analytics Report List").Items;
            if (listItems != null)
            {
                for (int i = listItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    listItems[i].Delete();
                }
            } 
      }    
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us where the exception is thrown...

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to Debug it? (restart service after deployment, attach to the owstimer proces..)
2. I use different approach in getting required site:

   `public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
       {
           var webApplication = Parent as SPWebApplication;
           if (webApplication == null) return;
           using (var site = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId].Sites[0])
           {
               var web = site.RootWeb;
               ...
           }
        }`